# Javascript not working while inserting image object in html

Tags: javascript

MAJOR EDIT: Re-Did a lot of things. But similar error.

```
var white = 1;
var turn = white;
var table = document.getElementById("game");

function createTable(table, white) {
    var i,j,tr;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++) 
    {
        tr = document.createElement('tr');

        for(j=0;j<8;j++)
            tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td')).id = String.fromCharCode( (white == 1 ? j : 8-j) +97)+(white == 1 ? 8-i : i+1);

        table.appendChild(tr);
    }

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            table.rows[i].cells[j].setAttribute("class","cell");
        }
    }
}

function onImageLoad(t) {

    console.log(t);
}

function createImageArray() {
    var w,c,p;
    var image = new Array(2);
    for(w=0;w<2;w++)
    {
        image[w] = new Array(2);
        for(c=0;c<2;c++)
        {
            image[w][c] = new Array(6);
            for(p=0;p<6;p++)
            {
                image[w][c][p] = new Array(2);
            }
        }
    }
    return image;
}

function createBlankimageArray() {
    var blank = new Array(2);
    return blank;
}

function bufferImages(image,blank) {

    var w, c, p, s, word;

    for(w=0;w<2;w++)
    {
        for(c=0;c<2;c++)
        {
            for(p=0;p<6;p++)
            {
                for(s=0;s<2;s++)
                {

                    word = w.toString() + c.toString() + (p+1).toString() + s.toString() + ".png";
                    //console.log(word);
                    image[w][c][p][s] = new Image();
                    image[w][c][p][s].onload = onImageLoad(word);
                    image[w][c][p][s].src='final images/'+ word;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        blank[i] = new Image();
        word = i.toString() + '.png';
        blank[i].onload = onImageLoad(word);
        blank[i].src= 'final images/'+ word;
    }
}

function intializeState() {

    var x,y,temp;
    var state = new Array(8);
    for(y=0;y<8;y++) 
    {
        state[y] = new Array(8);
        for(x=0;x<8;x++) 
        {
            state[y][x] = new Array(3);


            // Set Cell White or Black.
            state[y][x][0] = (x+y)%2;


            if(y==1 || y == 6) 
            {
                temp = 0;
                state[y][x][1] = temp;
                state[y][x][2] = ( white==1 ? 0 : 1);
            }
            else if(x==0 || x==7) {temp = 1;}
            else if(x==1 || x==6) {temp = 2;}
            else if(x==2 || x==5) {temp = 3;}
            else if(x==3) {temp = 4;}
            else if(x==4) {temp = 5;}

            if(temp!=0)
            {
                if(y==0)
                {
                    state[y][x][1] = temp;
                    state[y][x][2] = (white == 1 ? 0 : 1);
                }
                else if(y==7)
                {
                    state[y][x][1] = temp;
                    state[y][x][2] = (white == 1 ? 1 : 0);
                }
                else
                {   
                    state[y][x][1] = 7;
                    state[y][x][2] = 7;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return state;
}

function drawState(table,state,image,blank) {

    var y,x;
    //var table = document.getElementById("game");
    var w,c,p;

    for(y=0;y<8;y++)
    {
        for(x=0;x<8;x++)
        {
            c = state[y][x][0];
            w = state[y][x][1];
            p = state[y][x][2];
            if(p!=7)
            {
                table.rows[y].cells[x].appendChild(image[w][c][p][0]);
            }
            else
            {
                table.rows[y].cells[x].appendChild(blank[c]);
            }
        }
    }
}

var state = intializeState();
var image = createImageArray();
var blank = createBlankimageArray();
createTable(table, white);
bufferImages(image,blank);
intializeState(state);
drawState(table,state,image,blank);
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Anti Chess</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="game_title">Anti Chess by theManikJindal</h1>
    <a href="http://thylavatory.wordpress.com" target="_blank">Visit Blog!</a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <table id="game"></table>
    <script src="req_logic.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above script is required to create a chess board in the initial position. 
The problem that I am encountering is in the drawState function.

Console: (has printed out all the image names after loading them) After that:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined req_logic.js:154
```

Which is the line: `table.rows[y].cells[x].appendChild(image[w][c][p][0]);`

so where have I gone wrong.

EDIT: jsFiddle.net link : http://jsfiddle.net/8H3Ha/1/

Comment: This would be a lot easier if there were a jsfiddle.net provided...

Comment: Seconding Brad's comment: please, post [a minimal/sscce](http://sscce.org/) [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: sorry @alex23 just updated the question.

what is jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @DavidThomas I have 50 image resources, do I have to enter them one at a time! *mini scream*

Comment: There's no global variable named `state`. The function `initializeState` initializes a local variable, not a global array.

Comment: 4th line from the top, state is declared. i guess that makes it a global variable.

Comment: Didn't see that. But `initializeState()` is updateing its local variable, because it uses `state` as a parameter variable.

Comment: okay, shifted to your version. it's doing fine, similarily shifted things for image also, and for blank too. But still not working completely

Comment: In initializeState you have state[y][x][1] being set to values (temp) larger than 1. Looking at createImageArray, 'w' should be less than 2. You use state[y][x][1] to set your 'w' values. I'm not positive, but maybe you want     table.rows[y].cells[x].appendChild(image[p][c][w][0]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the definition ot `initializeState()` to:

```
function intializeState() {

    var x,y,temp;
    var state = new Array(8);
    for(y=0;y<8;y++) 
    {
        state[y] = new Array(8);
        for(x=0;x<8;x++) 
        {
            state[y][x] = new Array(3);


            // Set Cell White or Black.
            state[y][x][0] = (x+y)%2;


            if(y==1 || y == 6) 
            {
                temp = 0;
                state[y][x][1] = temp;
                state[y][x][2] = ( white==1 ? 0 : 1);
            }
            else if(x==0 || x==7) {temp = 1;}
            else if(x==1 || x==6) {temp = 2;}
            else if(x==2 || x==5) {temp = 3;}
            else if(x==3) {temp = 4;}
            else if(x==4) {temp = 5;}

            if(temp!=0)
            {
                if(y==0)
                {
                    state[y][x][1] = temp;
                    state[y][x][2] = (white == 1 ? 0 : 1);
                }
                else if(y==7)
                {
                    state[y][x][1] = temp;
                    state[y][x][2] = (white == 1 ? 1 : 0);
                }
                else
                {   
                    state[y][x][1] = 7;
                    state[y][x][2] = 7;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

Then call it as:

```
state = initializeState();
```

The problem is that the parameter variable named `state` was shadowing the global variable with the same name inside `initializeState`.

I also suggest that the elements of the `state` array should be objects, not arrays. Arrays should be used when the elements are uniform, but each of these sub-elements have different purposes: [0] is the cell color, [1] is the piece, and [2] is the piece color.

Comment: it is still not working. About your suggestion for the state array, the elements are uniform. For me they are just images. The game logic would not be implemented on javascript. It is on the server end. So, I guess making it an array is more than okay!

Comment: They aren't images. `// Set Cell White or Black. state[y][x][0] = (x+y)%2;`

Comment: the state array is just there to preserve the state. No logic would be working upon them. Its like a reference, for the drawing function.
BTW updated a lot of things which u suggested. still similar error. See the jsFiddle link

Comment: What you have will work, it's just poor programming style. Any time you're hard-coding indexes, like `c = state[y][x][0];` it's a strong suggestion that you should be using objects, so it would become `c = state[y][x].color;`. This makes the intent more obvious.

Comment: +1 for making me realize {This makes the intent more obvious)